# Can't figure out this table arrangement

Tags: lua, roblox

```
--The view of the table
local originalStats = {
    Info = {Visit = false, Name = "None", Characters = 1},
    Stats = {Levels = 0, XP = 0, XP2 = 75, Silver = 95},
    Inventory = {
        Hats = {"NoobHat"},
        Robes = {"NoobRobe"},
        Boots = {"NoobBoot"},
        Weapons = {"NoobSword"}
        }
    }
local tempData = {}

--The arrangement here
function Module:ReadAll(player)
  for k,v in pairs(tempData[player]) do
    if type(v) == 'table' then
      for k2, v2 in pairs(v) do
            print(k2) print(v2)
            if type(v2) == 'table'  then        
                for k3, v3 in pairs(v2) do
                    print(k3) print(v3)
                end
            else
                print(k2) print(v2)
            end
      end
    else
        print(k) print(v)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm sorry, but I can't seem to figure out how to arrange this 'ReadAll' function to where It'll show all the correct stats in the right orders.
The output is something like this:

```
Boots
table: 1A73CF10
1
NoobBoot
Weapons
table: 1A7427F0
1
NoobSword
Robes
table: 1A743D50
1
NoobRobe
Hats
table: 1A73C9D0
1
NoobHat
XP2
75
XP2
75
Levels
2
Levels
2
XP
0
XP
0
```

Comment: What means "in the right orders"?  What order is right?  What is the desired output?

Comment: I want to output all the value in info, stats, hats, robes, boots, weapons with out the same value repeating, how would I do it? I test it for hours but that's all I got.

Comment: Give an example of input table (tempData[player]) and output you want to obtain.

Comment: Maybe just removing the first line `print(k2) print(v2)` (you have two of them) ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to print all the elements without double or table reference values showing up. 
As the name states, this function will print all the elements within a table, no matter how many nested tables there are inside it. I don't have a way to order them at the moment, but I'll update my answer if I find a way. You can also get rid of the empty spaces in the print line, I just used it so it would look neater. Let me know if it works.

```
function allElementsInTable(table)
    for k,v in pairs(table) do
        if type(table[k]) == 'table' then
            print(k .. ":")
            allElementsInTable(v)
        else
            print("  " .. k .. " = " .. tostring(v))
        end
    end
end

--place the name of your table in the parameter for this function
allElementsInTable(originalStats)
```

Answer (score 1):

After more experimenting, I got this, if anyone wants it, feel free to use it.

```
tempData = { Info = {Visit = false, Name = 'None'},
    Stats = {LVL = 0, XP = 0, Silver = 75},
    Inventory = { Armors = {'BasicArmor'},
    Weapons = {'BasicSword'} }

    }


    function Read()
    for i, v in pairs(tempData['Info']) do
     print(i..'\t',v)
    end
    ----------
    for i2, v2 in pairs(tempData['Stats']) do
     print(i2..'\t',v2)
    end
    ----------
    for i3, v3 in pairs(tempData['Inventory']) do
     print(i3..':')
     for i4, v4 in pairs(v3) do
        print('\t',v4)
     end
    end
    end

    Read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect table's fields to be iterated with `pairs()` in some specific order. Internally Lua tables are hashtables, and the order of fields in it is not specified at all. It will change between runs, you can't have them iterated in the same order as they were filled.
Only arrays with consecutive integer indices will maintain the order of their elements.

Comment: If this is not possible, is it possible to some how put the table back to how they where when loading from datatstore, how would I do it?

Comment: You just load whatever you have, exact loading order is not important. It's only important to have some fields with known names and expected content.

Comment: I posted an answer, but I was wondering if what I did in the following, will change order?
Temp = {}
Orig = {Info = {Visit = false, Name = 'None'},
Inventory = {Hat = {'Basic'},
Robe = {'Basic'}
}}

Temp = Orig -- When I move the Orig values into Temp, will the order change? How about when I save the codes then load it?

Comment: The order of elements in table (as seen by `pairs()`) is not guaranteed to be the same as the order of assigning those elements. In your suggested answer you explicitly read some elements in some predefined order, but that has nothing to do with pairs(). And elements within those tables - like LVL,XP,Silver - still may change order any time you create new table with those elements and/or if table storing elements will be rehashed due to adding new elements. Btw, do you really need some specific order anyway?

Comment: Why do you need some order? Is there any real difference for you if save will look like {XP=100, LVL=8,Silver=1000} or {LVL=8,XP=100,Silver=100} or {Silver=1000,XP=100,LVL=8} ? Your script will just read required data like `save.Stats.LVL`, and it doesn't care about any orders out there.